# Flutter setState from a different Screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, setstate

Activity1

```
static String mValue = "0";

change(){
  setState((){
    Activity1.mValue = "1";
 });
}
```

Activity2

```
Text(Activity1.mValue)
```

This is the simplest form of my code. I want to change the static value present in Activity1 and that change should be reflected in Activity2

What Works so far

```
// Activity2
setState((){
  Activity1.mValue = "1";
})
Text(Activity1.mValue);
```

What I want to achieve is change the value from Activity1 and have it reflected in Activity2. They are 2 different classes and are not Root and Child. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter we don't change the state of one widget from another widget directly, as Flutter is a declarative framework.

Take a look at [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) approaches section in Flutter docs, and especially [Lifting state up](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up) section.

The main idea is that you lift your state in the widget that is above both `Activity1` and `Activity2`, change it there (e.g. using callbacks) and then propagate the state down the tree.